# Is UserDefaults.setValue() documented anywhere?

Tags: ios, userdefaults, kvc

I have seen people using `UserDefaults.setValue()` occasionally. Below is an example I find [here](https://medium.com/axel-springer-tech/swift-property-wrappers-user-defaults-and-unique-default-values-e8725d7154a2) and it works fine.

```
@propertyWrapper struct AppSetting<Value> {
    let key: String
    let defaultValue: Value
    var container: UserDefaults = .standard

    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get { container.value(forKey: key) as? Value ?? defaultValue}
        set { container.setValue(newValue, forKey: key) }
    }
}
```

From what I can find in Apple's docs, `setValue()` is an API of `NSObject` for its KVO feature, and `UserDefaults` class inherits from `NSObject`. However, it's not clear what the API exactly does when it's called on `UserDefaults`. From the above example, I can guess it (it seems that `UserDefaults` overrides this method). But otherwise I'd think it sets a property of a `UserDefaults` obect, which is meaningless. So I wonder how people find this usage? Is it documented anywhere?

**UPDATE**: I probably didn't describe my question clearly. I knew what KVO is. What I'm confused is how KVO relates to UserDefaults. From my understanding, **the key in KVO and that in UserDefaults have completely different meaning**. Key in KVO is property of an object. Key in UserDefaults is the key in key/value data store. So my questions is: how the API for KVO can be used to update a key/value pair in data store? Could it be that `UserDefaults` instance creates properties for each key in the data store? But that is an implementation detail and it's not obvious to me.

**UPDATE 2**: as @rob-mayoff and @HangarRash pointed out, `setValue()` is an API for KVC, not KVO. That said, I think the original question is still valid.

Comment: You actually seem to mean KVC, not KVO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are actually asking about KVC (key-value coding) and not KVO (key-value observing) since you are asking about KVC methods `setValue:forKey:`/`valueForKey:` and not about KVO methods such as `addObserver...` and `observeValueForKeyPath:...`.

You state:  *"Key in KVO is property of an object.*"

Not necessarily. If you go through the [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107-SW1) you will find the following basic summary (emphasis mine):

- Access object properties.
- **Manipulate collection properties.**
- Invoke collection operators on collection objects.
- Access non-object properties.
- Access properties by key path.

Look at `NSMutableDictionary` for an example of using KVC with a collection. `UserDefaults` (`NSUserDefaults`) is basically a wrapper around a dictionary. So the same KVC rules that apply to a dictionary apply to user defaults.

More details on this can be found at [Accessing Collection Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/AccessingCollectionProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107i-CH4-SW1) and [Accessor Search Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/SearchImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000955-CJBBBFFA).

Note that with simple keys, `setValue:forKey:`/`valueForKey:` are the same as `setObject:forKey:`/`objectForKey:`. And the various `UserDefaults` APIs are just type safe wrappers around `setObject:forKey:`/`objectForKey:`.

In the end, unless you have specific needs for KVC, use the supplied API of `UserDefaults` and avoid using `setValueForKey:/valueForKey:`.

Comment: Thanks. Your explanation is very helpful. The only thing I'm not sure is your statement that "UserDefaults (NSUserDefaults) is basically a wrapper around a dictionary". That's not how I perceived `UserDefaults` worked in the past (I thought it as a black box). But I think your explanation makes sense.

Comment: At least the old Objective-C `NSUserDefaults` is effectively an `NSDictionary` that is stored in a plist file. `NSUserDefaults` just adds some type safe methods over and above `setObjectForKey:/objectForKey:` (plus a few other bits of functionality). `NSUserDefaults` puts restrictions that keys must be strings and the values must be of limited types. Those restrictions are due to being stored in a plist file. The Swift `UserDefaults` is just `NSUserDefaults` with Swift APIs.

Answer (score 5):

`UserDefaults` is [documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) to support [key-value observing (KVO)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177i), so that you can use KVO to be notified when specific settings are changed:

> You can use key-value observing to be notified of any updates to a particular default value.

KVO-compliance [generally implies](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-BAJEAIEE) support for [key-value coding (KVC)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107-SW1):

> In order to be considered KVO-compliant for a specific property, a class must ensure the following:
>
> - The class must be key-value coding compliant for the property, as specified in Ensuring KVC Compliance.

The `value(forKey:)` and `setValue(forKey:)` methods are part of KVC.

However, I would recommend sticking to the `UserDefaults`-specific methods as they might be implemented more efficiently.

Comment: Rob, thanks for your answer. I probably didn't describe my question clearly. I knew what KVO is. What I'm confused is how KVO relates to `UserDefaults`. I mean, the key in KVO and that in `UserDefaults` have completely different meaning. Key in KVO is property of an object. Key in `UserDefaults` is the key in key/value data store. While I'm writing this comment, I realize it's very likely that `UserDefaults` also creates properties for each key, right? That would explain why KVO API works for it.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't read your answer carefully. You actually answered my original question (it is documented). I upvoted your answer, but I'll choose HangarRash's answer as the accepted one because he explained the details how `UserDefaults` supported KVC.